# How can I programmatically know when a user installs my outlook add in

Tags: installation, outlook, outlook-addin, manifest

I wanted to check if the user installed my outlook add in .Is there any event triggered when the installation happens?

Do we have any provision to add an end point in manifest file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific events for that. You can check a new installation in your add-in's code at first launch and report back to the server. You can also use analytics info from the seller dashboard, see [New Office Add-ins Analytics Report in Universal Store Dev Center and Seller Dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/new-office-add-in-analytics-report-in-universal-store-dev-center-and-seller-dashboard/) for more information.